# In-app menu display settings modification

Tags: settings, appearance, locally-integrated-menus

I would like to modify the way the menu is displayed so that the the program in image 1 is displayed as in image 2, all the time without having to hover the mouse above it.

So that this:
[image]

changes to this:

[image]

Thanks!